# remove localisation on android

Tags: android, localization

is there a way to disable localisation on an android app without simply removing/commenting out all the different string language/layouts?

I want to avoid commenting out all the layouts and string values used for different languages and instead disable localisation so that when a user uses this app and has there location set to a specific language, i want the app to not be able to switch to the appropriate language.

I also want to avoid creating a fancy complex gradle flavour that removes/includes the multi language if possible.

Is there no settings in the manifest that does this?

Comment: Force your desired locale at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as no one had any suggestions i managed to figure out how.

for anyone interested, this is how you do it

```
 private void forceEnLocal() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);

    }
```

Enjoy

Comment: `Seeing as no one had any suggestions`... Maybe you didn't read my comment: it says **exactly this**

Comment: Ha true. Did not see it. Cheers mate